# Running a website in a sub-folder using a separate web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I was wondering if it is possible to run an aspx.net website in a sub folder if it has it's own web.config with forms auth and is using a role mananger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this for nested applications recently.  Its not too difficult.

In addition to having access the same data store for credential and role data, you need to:

- make sure the the machineKeys are the same for both web applications
- configure loginUrl's to resolve to the same absolute path
- if you're using cookies you need to make sure that the domain is set to a value available to both web applications
- also for cookies, if your web applications are nested at diferent levels in a domain make sure that the path attribute is set to "/"

See [this blog post](http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2012/03/cross-domain-forms-authentication-with.html) for more detail on getting forms authentication working.

Another issue particular to nested applications is that by default your nested web.config will inherit settings from the parent app's web.config.  This means that you may need to strip out some items in the child config that are in the parent config, and remove items that are currently in the child app config but would already be present in the parent config.  See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you setup this sub directory as different asp.net application from iis

Answer (score 0):

I think there won't be any problems if you use Virtual Directory. Look here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-86.aspx

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried this, but the Virtual Directory also inherits the site roots web.config which is a pain

Answer (score 0):

Authentication can only be set in config for all applications, or root folder of web application. Same for setting session. You can use sub folder. But it has to be its own application , so basically it doesn't make a ton of sense to have it as subfolder of another application.